# Installed latest version of libav from sources but the corresponding libavcodec shared library apparently is not detected

Tags: 14.04, firefox, compiling, avconv

After I upgraded to Firefox 50, a new warning message started to be displayed for some of the videos (or animated gifs) that I tried to play or load. The actual text message is `libavcodec may be vulnerable or is not supported, and should be updated to play video`. The obsolete versions are those prior to 54.35.1.

Having seen this I checked for the avaiable libav version in the repositories, but sadly a newer one was not available for trusty. So I downloaded the sources for the last available libav (version 12) library, compiled and installed it.

After the install `libavcodec.so -> libavcodec.so.57.25.0`, `libavcodec.so.57 -> libavcodec.so.57.25.0` and `libavcodec.so.57.25.0` are available inside `/usr/local/lib`.

I created a new conf file for `/usr/local/lib` inside `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/`, executed `ldconfig` as root and then tried againg to see if the warning message is not displayed anymore. But unfortunately the problem still persists.

The question is, after I installed the latest version of libavcodec, and the corresponding .so files are available, why are they not detected? I mean, ok, the obsolete version is available inside `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`, but shouldn't the newer version preside?

What am I missing?

Comment: On Launchpad we have [bug 1643467](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1643467) about libav and Firefox problem. See other topic here [How to update libavcodec on ubuntu 14.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/851190/how-to-update-libavcodec-on-ubuntu-14-04).