# Netflix error code F7355-1204 and F7363-1260

Tags: 12.04, firefox, wine, netflix

Netflix quit and displayed error codes F7355-1204 and F7363-1260. It will go to the point where the movie is downloading but stops and displays the error codes.
My os is Ubuntu 12.04 on a 32 bit machine. Netflix was working fine on the pipelight approach. Reinstalled firefox 52.0.2. Fixed libavcodec. Have yet to reinstall pipelight.

What are these error codes, and how do I fix them.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/828286/now-that-i-have-firefox-49-or-higher-how-do-i-watch-netflix?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: I know that for 16.04, netflix works in [Chrome](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/desktop/index.html) (Downloaded from Google, not Chromium in the repos). Install and point your browser to Netflix. Mileage may vary in 12.04.

Comment: See the linked question and answer, but it only worked on 32 bit machines for me in Firefox 49. Quit working in later releases.  The only option I found for my ancient 32 bit netbook is to keep the last 32 bit version of Chrome and use it for Netflix only.

Comment: I am running a 32 bit machine. Firefox has always worked great, so I saw no need to get chrome. Now, 32 bit chrome is not available, so I have try to fix the problem with firefox. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Chrome *is* available for 32-bit Linux; it'll just be outdated and insecure to use on untrusted sites. Netflix should be fine though as Organic Marble suggests.

Comment: IT IS! Very good. Thank you the command line is: sudo apt-get install chromium-browser I have downloaded it and it works. However, all of the warnings are made explicit. On the downside, Netflix still doesn't work. I just tried Hulu with the same result. It wants me to download the .tar.gz version of Flash Player. I have it already. With a little research, I found a version on Software Center, so I replaced the version I have with that one.  Still no soap. Still a learning process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clear your Firefox (version 52 or higher only) caches by going to Preferences, Advanced, Network tab, and click the **Clear Now** buttons, shown below...

[image]

Comment: Did the Cache clean up and reinstalled pipelight. This eliminated error code F7355-1204, but F7363-1260 remains. I am wondering if firefox updated and reset pipelight and libavcodec.

Comment: You should try uninstalling Pipelight. And what did you do with libavcodec? Please remember to vote my answer if it was helpful. Thanks.

Comment: When I first attempted to use Netflix, I got the message that the "libavcodec may be vulnerable or is not supported, and should be updated to play videos." When I reinstalled Firefox, the boolean value for libavec had been set to "false." I had to type "about:config" into the Firefox address bar and go in and change the value to true.  There is a real good discussion about it at https://askubuntu.com/questions/851190/how-to-update-libavcodec-on-ubuntu-14-04. This action did get rid of the F7355-1204 error.  It has been my experience that cleaning the cache is a good Idea,  thank you heynnema.

Comment: PS I still have the F7363-1260 error, and I have asked Netflix about it. They say to disable the extensions.  This does not work. I am waiting for another answer from them.

Comment: I would set all of the "about:config" settings back to default and try again.

Answer (score 5):

You need to install codec (copy and paste in the terminal).

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

Also, a browser extension may be causing the problem, try disabling them.

Comment: This is the **main answer!**  `sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras` is working with Ubuntu 20

Answer (score 0):

Google chrome is not Chromium so [this comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/906815/netflix-error-code-f7355-1204-and-f7363-1260#comment1425805_906815) doesn't get you where you need to go. When I was faced with this problem I upgraded my OS to 64-bit and installed the latest 64-bit version of chrome.

It doesn't sound like that's an option for you though, so if your comfortable using the last 32-bit version of chrome, it's still available as pointed out by [this comment by David.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/906815/netflix-error-code-f7355-1204-and-f7363-1260#comment1425369_906815) You can obtain the .deb package directly from the Internet Archive [here.](https://archive.org/download/google-chrome-stable_48.0.2564.116-1_i386/google-chrome-stable_48.0.2564.116-1_i386.deb)

Chrome plays Netflix videos flawlessly.

**Note** that there will be no further updates to this package (security or otherwise) so it would likely be prudent to restrict it's usage to Netflix only and **not** make it your default browser.