# Should I update libav codecs lirary from 9.18 to 11.3?

Tags: 14.04, apt, updates, libav

Concerning Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (Trusty)

Software Updater lists but does not allow ticking (checking) of box to update:

[_] Libav codecs library (additional codecs meta-package)

It reports:

> Changes for libavcodec-extra versions:
>
> > Installed version: 6:9.18-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
> >
> > Available version: 6:11.3-1~trusty
>
> This update does not come from a source that supports changelogs.

My streamed video playback is terrible (possibly because of bloatware on an old machine) but I'm wondering if I should update codecs.

1. Is there anything else to consider
2. How do I get it to automatically update (if it isn't properly)
3. Should I stop worrying and stop interfering?
4. I'm uncertain how Libavcodec54 relates to the version numbers above.
5. I don't want advice that leaves my system vulnerable or requiring future remembering of what I've done previously.  e.g. see AskUbuntu question [851190](https://askubuntu.com/questions/851190/how-to-update-libavcodec-on-ubuntu-14-04/851192)

Advice pitched for a noob, please.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the output of `apt-cache policy libavcodec-extra` as well. It looks like you've added some PPA, and PPAs are not inherently trustworthy (you need to explicitly trust the owner of the PPA to not be doing nasty things, as there isn't really any active moderation of PPAs). However, it's also very unlikely that this would improve video playback performance. You should rewrite your question to include specific details about that, instead of asking a subjective question about whether others think something _should_ be done or not.

Comment: " requiring future remembering of what I've done"   The use of ppa's represents some degree of user responsibility so probably not for you. Would be interesting to know which ppa you're getting those libav packages from.  Generally speaking libav11 has better codec support than 9 but performance is a separate issue..